# odoo 16 is it possible to auto open a form after login

Tags: forms, action, odoo-16

i want to auto open a form after user has logged in.
i tried this with setting the users home_action to a custom action.
i see in logfile that the action has run, but the form doesnt open.

i wrote a function in my module which is called by the action.

```
class kskassenbuch(models.Model):
_name = 'ks_sale.kskassenbuch'

ks_date = fields.Datetime(string="Zahlungsdatum")
ks_filiale = fields.Many2one('res.company', string = "Filiale")
ks_start_betrag = fields.Float(string="Kassenstart")
ks_end_betrag = fields.Float(string="Kassenschluss")
ks_kassen_zahlungen = fields.One2many('ks_sale.kskassenzahlungen', 'ks_kassen_id', string = "Kassen Zahlungen")
ks_description = fields.Text(string = "Notizen")

@api.model
def serveraction(self):
    view_id = self.env.ref('ks_sale.view_ks_sale_kassenbuch__form').id
    ctx = self.env.context
    #self.create_new_kassenbuch(ctx)
    _logger.info('aus  on_test_server_action view_id = %s, ctx = %s', view_id, ctx)
    
    return {
        'name':'view_ks_sale_kassenbuch__form',
        'view_type':'form',
        'view_mode':'form',
        'views' : [(view_id,'form')],
        'res_model':'ks_sale.kskassenbuch',
        'view_id':view_id,
        'type':'ir.actions.act_window',
        'type': 'ir.ui.view',
        'res_id':self.id,
        'target':'new',
        'context':ctx,
    }
```

and .xml:

```
<!-- Form to open -->
<record id="view_ks_sale_kassenbuch__form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">ks_sale.kassenbuch.form</field>
        <field name="model">ks_sale.kskassenbuch</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Kassenbuch">
                <sheet width="100%">
                    <group>
                        <field name="ks_date" string="Datum"/>
                        <field name="ks_filiale" string="Filiale"/>
                        <field name="ks_end_betrag" string="Kassenstart"/>
                        <field name="ks_end_betrag" string="Kassenschluss"/>
                        <field name="ks_kassen_zahlungen" string="Zahlungen"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

<!-- home_action of user -->
    <record id="action_new_kassenbuch" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Kassenbuch_Action</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_ks_sale_kskassenbuch"/>
        <field name="binding_model_id" ref="ks_sale.model_ks_sale_kskassenbuch"/>
        <field name="binding_view_types">form</field>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">model.serveraction()</field>
    </record>
```

i'm asking myself if this it is possible to auto open a form. with buttons it is possible

thx for any answer

Comment: Why not simply use a window action?